# I am running a query using fetch and offset but confused with the behaviour of same

Tags: sql-server

I am very confused as a null set is also a set this is true!
But when i am executing a query like

```
SELECT FirstName
,LastName 
,EmailPromotion
FROM person.Person
ORDER BY LastName desc
OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH FIRST 0 ROW ONLY
```

Its giving an error 
The number of rows provided for a FETCH clause must be greater then zero.

And at the same time when i am executing a query like this

```
DECLARE @n AS BIGINT = 0;
SELECT FirstName
,LastName 
,EmailPromotion
FROM person.Person
ORDER BY LastName desc
OFFSET @n ROW FETCH FIRST @n ROW ONLY
```

Its again giving an error 
The number of rows provided for a FETCH clause must be greater then zero.

But when i am executing a query like this its not giving any error and rightfully generates an empty set

```
DECLARE @n AS BIGINT = 0;
SELECT FirstName
,LastName 
,EmailPromotion
FROM person.Person
ORDER BY LastName desc
OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH FIRST @n ROW ONLY
```

Why is that can someone explain this behaviour please?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?  `OFFSET` lets you skip some number of initial records (as defined by an ordering).  `FETCH FIRST` looks like DB2, not SQL Server, the latter which uses `FETCH NEXT`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - SQL Server supports both [FIRST and NEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm clueless about latest extensions in most RDBMS...thanks for the link, reading now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you can use both next and first depends on you but it is only for the sake of convenience that if you're offsetting 0 row then you should use fetch next. Next and First both are supported by sql server.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `FETCH 0` basically saying "fetch nothing," hence the error?  Maybe you should describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Exaclty fetch nothing means fetch an empty set then why its giving error like try to fetch something you're fetching nothing.But it should not work for this query as well DECLARE @n AS BIGINT = 0;
SELECT FirstName
,LastName 
,EmailPromotion
FROM person.Person
ORDER BY LastName desc
OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH FIRST @n ROW ONLY

Comment: This is not based on anything concrete, but is merely a guess. I am guessing that the reason the last statement works is actually more of a glitch than anything. The first statement sets both values to 0, in which case SQL Server correctly throws the error when parsing the whole statement. In the second case, it evaluates @r when it's parsing the `SELECT` part, and it determines this is pretty much identical to scenario 1. In the latter case, the value set for @n might not be parsed until actual execution, and thus it tricks the engine into running the statement.

Answer (score 4):

There are many issues with SQL that make it clear that, whilst it's *inspired* by set-based logic, it's not rigorously set-based. This would appear to be the case here where, [per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql), it's incorrect to use a zero value for `FETCH`.

Other examples where SQL falls down with respect to empty sets include not allowing tables with no columns (which can be interesting as degenerate cases) as well as not allowing *keys* to be declared with no columns (where the table should contain 0 or exactly 1 row)<sup>1</sup>

So whilst we can say that empty sets *are* interesting, that doesn't necessarily mean that SQL is going to help you in generating them. The case you've found where it does seem to allow it to happen would appear to be more of a case of "tricking the optimizer" than something you should rely upon in production code.

---

<sup>1</sup>IIRC, in [The Third Manifesto](http://www.thethirdmanifesto.com) Date and Darwen refer to these as some of SQL's "nullogical" errors. Other set-based issues include the fact that tables and result sets are allowed to have duplicate rows and so may be bags rather than sets.

Answer (score 0):

because your passing page size is zero so therse no records for OFFSET, is you pass page size issue will be resolve